# If $fg$ is bounded, then $f$ and $g$ are bounded

Tags: functions, proof-writing

False, the above statement is not true, suppose $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1/x$ where $x \neq 0$.

How do I prove that $f$ and $g$ are not bounded because:

$|fg|\leq1$.

Comment: Are you sure you want to define it for $x!=0$ and not $x \neq 0$?

Comment: @SahibaArora i didnt know how to do that

Comment: @SahibaArora by $x!=0$ he probably means $x \neq 0$, in some coding languages (java for example), it's written this way (it's mistaken for mathematics, just clarifying it to you.

Comment: You can write the symbol $\neq$ with \neq

Comment: $f, g$ are unbounded by themselves in $\mathbb{R}$, not because $|fg| \leq 1$, but your proof is already finished reasoning-wise

Comment: @SahibaArora, after $\exists$ the exclamation mark means *unique*. After a natural number, it means *factorial*: $n! = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (n-1) \cdot n.$

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ is clearly not bounded. Further,
$$g(x) \to \infty \text{ as } x \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to do anything here. 
Look at the function $f(x)$, if you take the limit as $x \to \infty$ you will have:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty $

so it's obvious that it is not bounded. Are you trying to prove a more general statement?